# Moving mapping from old ElasticSearch to latest ES (5)

Tags: json, elasticsearch, mapping

I've inherited some pretty old (v2.something) ElasticSearch instance running in cloud somewhere and need to get the data out starting with mappings to local instance of latest ES (v5). Unfortunately, it fails with following error:

```
% curl -X PUT  'http://127.0.0.1:9200/easysearch?pretty=true' --data @easysearch_mapping.json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "unknown setting [index.easysearch.mappings.espdf.properties.abstract.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "unknown setting [index.easysearch.mappings.espdf.properties.abstract.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

The mapping I got from old instance does contain some fields of this kind:

```
  "espdf" : {
    "properties" : {
      "abstract" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "document" : {
        "type" : "attachment",
        "fields" : {
          "content" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "author" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
```

This "espdf" thing probably comes from Meteor's "EasySearch" component, but I have more structures like this in the mapping and new ES rejects each of them (I tried editing the mapping and deleting the "espdf" key and value).

How can I get the new ES to accept the mapping? Is this some legacy issue from 2.x ES and I should somehow convert this to new 5.x ES format?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it fails is because the older ES had a plugin installed called [mapper-attachments](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.1/mapper-attachments.html), which would add the `attachment` mapping type to ES.

In ES 5, this plugin has been replace by the [ingest-attachment](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.1/ingest-attachment.html) plugin, which you can install like this:

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment
```

After running this command in your ES_HOME folder, restart your ES cluster and it should go better.